# How to pass details from a table in partial view to text boxes in parent view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, partial-views

I have a form wherein there are many text boxes in parent view and a table containing all these details in a partial view. On click event of a row, how can I pass the details from a table in partial view to the same text boxes in parent view which was used to insert the details?

Comment: by `click` event, do you mean javascript click or server postback click?

Comment: javascript click event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's javascript click event, you need to ensure HTML are generated correctly.

I've written the code to populate form fields from a table row click.

Hope it helps.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $("table tr").click(function() {
    var form = $("form"),
      tr = $(this);

    // Text
    form.find(".text").val(tr.find("td:eq(0)").text());

    // Radio
    var radioValue = tr.find("td:eq(1)").data("value");
    form.find(".radio").each(function() {
      this.checked = this.value == radioValue;
    });

    // Checkbox
    var checkboxValues = tr.find("td:eq(2)").text().split(',');
    form.find(".checkbox").each(function() {
      this.checked = $.inArray(this.value, checkboxValues) >= 0;
    });

    // Dropdown
    form.find(".dropdown").val(tr.find("td:eq(3)").data('value'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  Text:
  <input type="text" class="text" />
  <br/>Radio:
  <input type="radio" class="radio" name="radioName" value="1" />yes
  <input type="radio" class="radio" name="radioName" value="0" />no
  <br/>Checkbox:
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="Cat" />Cat
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="Dog" />Dog
  <br/>Dropdown:
  <select class="dropdown">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">Monday</option>
    <option value="2">Tuesday</option>
    <option value="3">Wednesday</option>
    <option value="4">Thursday</option>
    <option value="5">Friday</option>
    <option value="6">Saturday</option>
    <option value="7">Sunday</option>
  </select>
</form>
<hr/>
<table border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Text 1</td>
      <td data-value="1">Yes</td>
      <td>Cat</td>
      <td data-value="3">Wednesday</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Text 2</td>
      <td data-value="0">No</td>
      <td>Dog</td>
      <td data-value="5">Friday</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Text 3</td>
      <td data-value="1">Yes</td>
      <td>Cat,Dog</td>
      <td data-value="7">Sunday</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```